# Jquery Issue with fadeTo on hover

Tags: jquery, html, fadeto

So basically I am trying to have `div.show` fade in on hover and then when you stop hovering, have it fade back to an opacity of 0.

However, I cannot get the div to fade back to 0 when you stop hovering.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.post.photo").live('hover', function() {
        $(this).children("div.show").fadeTo("slow", .7);
    }, function(){
        $(this).children("div.show").fadeTo("slow", 0);
    });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you should be fading it back to 1, not 0.
Also `live()` only takes one handler. You need to append mouse out event separately.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liho1eye/3mBhj/)

Comment: That does not worth either :/

Comment: That's the opposite of what he is trying to do. It's supposed to fade out, not back to 100% opacity

Comment: @NateB and as I noted in my answer I think that is the opposite of what he actually needs. Unless precondition is that `.show` starts as 0 opacity, but there is nothing about that in the OP. Regardless, it only takes changing 1 to 0 and adding `opacity:0` to the `.show` to flip this around.

Comment: Sorry about that, it is set to display none in css.

Comment: Well, this works.  Thanks a bunch, I had to change the numbers, which was fine.  Interesting that delegate works without the use of live on new elements, whereas on does not?

Comment: You shouldn't need to bind them separately, you can just check the `event.type` to see what kind of event was triggered, if it was `mouseenter` or `mouseleave`

Answer (score 2):

You need to explicitly check for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events using the `event.type`. You shouldn't need to bind them twice.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.post.photo").live('hover', function(event) {

        if( event.type === 'mouseenter') 
            $(this).children("div.show").fadeTo("slow", .7);
        else if( event.type === 'mouseleave' )
            $(this).children("div.show").fadeTo("slow", 0);
    });
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/VdyVh/). Personally i would use `.on` but i'm not sure what version of jQuery you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I find that this works if you use `.hover()` instead of `.live()`, so I think the issue is that `.live()` doesn't support the hover event, perhaps because `.live()` only has one handler function, not two.

In jQuery 1.7+, this seems to work (breaking it up into two event handlers and modernizing to `.on()`):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document.body).on("mouseenter", "div.post.photo",
        function() {
            $(this).children("div.show").fadeTo("slow", .7);
        }
    );

    $(document.body).on("mouseleave", "div.post.photo",
        function() {
            $(this).children("div.show").fadeTo("slow", .0);
        }
    );
});
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/YV2nU/.

FYI, I switched to `.on()` because `.live()` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7+.

Comment: Hmm, my issue is that I use an infinite scroll script that fetches new posts when you scroll to the bottom of a page.  Thus the live allowed the script to continue working on new elements.  When I use your suggestion the script does not work on any new `div.post.photo`'s fetched.

Comment: I could help if I could see your actual page.  Aside from that, `.on()` is a direct replacement for `.live()` so it should offer the same dynamic behavior.  The one thing you could improve in my code example is to change `document.body` to a parent div that is always there, but closer to the items that are dynamically added.

Comment: However, I used an answer above that used `delegate` instead of `on` and it works like a champ.  Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `hover` is not a Javascript event, it is JQuery shorthand for the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events, so it can't be used in the `live` method like that. You need to bind them separately. Additionally, you should note that the `.live()` method is deprecated. The [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/) gives instruction on what methods are better to use.